# How do I get the highlight color of the current Blackberry theme?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, themes, look-and-feel

I've implemented some custom fields and would like to keep the look-and-feel consistent with the current Blackberry theme. So I would like the highlighting color of the fields to be consistent with the highlight color used throughout the BB apps.

How can I get the this color?

**Edit:** Apparently, there's [no way](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&view=by_date_ascending&message.id=8414#M8414) to get those kinds of colors from any API. So is there a work-around way to getting these colors?

Comment: Hi, please describe the "highlighting color" term. Is it color of focused background or color of text selection or anything else?

Comment: The background color of a focused item. The default theme on the simulator has a color of `0x1055ad` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we can do is test colors on drawFocus method of some custom text field:

```
class TestField extends TextField {
    TestThemeListener mListener;
    public TestField(TestThemeListener listener) {
        super(EDITABLE | FOCUSABLE);
        setText("Hello this is a color test");
        setSelection(0, true, 10);
        mListener = listener;
    }
    protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on) {
        drawHighlightRegion(g, HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS, true, 0, 0, 50, 20);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(50, 20);
        Display.screenshot(bmp, 0, 0, 50, 20);
        int[] argbData = new int[1];
        bmp.getARGB(argbData, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        int focusColor = argbData[0];
        drawHighlightRegion(g, HIGHLIGHT_SELECT, true, 50, 0, 50, 20);
        Display.screenshot(bmp, 50, 0, 50, 20);
        argbData = new int[1];
        bmp.getARGB(argbData, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        int selectionColor = argbData[0];
        if (null != mListener) {
            mListener.themeTested(focusColor, selectionColor);
            mListener = null;
        }
    }
}

interface TestThemeListener {
    void themeTested(int focusColor, int selectionColor);
}
```

And use it on the screen:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen implements TestThemeListener {
    LabelField mSelectionColorName;
    LabelField mFocusColorName;
    public Scr() {
        add(new TestField(this));
    }
    public void themeTested(int focusColor, int selectionColor) {
        add(new LabelField("Theme colors (AARRGGBB)"));
        add(new LabelField("Focus : " + focusColor));
        Bitmap bmpF = new Bitmap(100, 20);
        Graphics gF = new Graphics(bmpF);
        gF.setColor(focusColor);
        gF.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 20);
        add(new BitmapField(bmpF));
        add(new LabelField("Selection : " + selectionColor));
        Bitmap bmpS = new Bitmap(100, 20);
        Graphics gS = new Graphics(bmpS);
        gS.setColor(selectionColor);
        gS.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 20);
        add(new BitmapField(bmpS));
    }
}
```

[color test app screenshot http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/8943/830001.png](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/8943/830001.png)

Comment: You're essentially just poking at a pixel in a screen shot to get its color. This seems like a really round-about way to get the info. This also requires use of the signed API (`Display` requires signing). I would prefer a solution that is more efficient than taking a screen-shot and doesn't require signing.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine but there is a problem. The application must be signed and it displays a confirmation to the user to take the screen shots like "Application xxx wants to take a screen shot. Allow?" This could be annoying to the user. This is caused by using a secure API in the device class.

Instead, try creating a new `Graphics` from a `Bitmap`, then draw on it.

```
class TestField : extends Field {
    int getHighlightColor() {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(getWidth(), getHeight());
        Graphics g = new Graphics(image).
        drawHighlightRegion(g, Field.HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS, true, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        paint(
        argbData = new int[1];
        image.getARGB(argbData, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        return argbData[0];
    }
}
```